# errore SQLstate 23000 i can t save some values of JSON into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, request

I need to save some values of a JSON into my database SQL.

Database  - Table "confrontations"
[image]

---

This is my PHP code

```
require_once("database.php");
$apiURL = 'https://nico.planethoster.world/api-foot/confrontations/lire.php?annee=2020&semaine=29';
$response = file_get_contents($apiURL);
$jsonResponse = json_decode($response, true);
$items = $jsonResponse['match'];



    foreach ($items as $item ) {
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO `confrontations`(`id_match`, `id_equipe1`, `id_equipe2`, `cote1`, `coteN`, `cote2`, `date`, `heure`, `semaine`) 
        VALUES (:id_match, :id_equipe1, :id_equipe2, :cote1, :coteN, :cote2, :date, :heure, :semaine) ";
        $check = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $date = $item["date"];
        $heure = $item["heure"];
        $check->bindParam(':id_match', $item["id_match"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $check->bindParam(':id_equipe1', $item["id_equipe1"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $check->bindParam(':id_equipe2', $item["id_equipe2"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $check->bindParam(':cote1', $item["cote1"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->bindParam(':coteN', $item["coteN"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->bindParam(':cote2', $item["cote2"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->bindValue(':date', $date,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->bindValue(':heure', $heure, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->bindParam(':semaine', $item["semaine"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $check->execute();
```

and that s my error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save a row where the primary key (id_match) already exists. So multiple confrontations use the same id_match.

Maybe you already ran this code once. If you run it the second time you have to implement some update routine instead of an insert. E.g. `UPDATE confrontations SET x = y WHERE id_match = z`;